# Show that the quotient space $[0,2]/]1,2]$ is not homeomorphic to an interval of $\Bbb{R}$.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

My idea is to see the domain as $[0,1] \cup [2]$, where $[2]$ is the equivalence class under the quotient map. I suppose I have to assume for a contradiction that $[0,1] \cup [2]$ is mapped homeomorphically by $f$ to an interval $[a,b]$ of $\Bbb{R}$, but I don't know how to go further.

Comment: In $[0,2]/(1,2]$, there is an open singleton, which never occurs in any interval of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Only until I read Mindlack's comment I realized the question has $\;]1,2]=(1,2]\;$ in that quotient...! That notation for open intervals, which I think is very common in France, can be pretty confusing...

Comment: @Mindlack can you elaborate more why that $[2]$ would cause a problem? Thanks.

Comment: @ensbana: Assume there is a homeomorphism $f : I \rightarrow [0,2]/(1,2]$. Then $f^{-1}(\{[2]\})$ is an open singleton in $I$, which is impossible.

Answer (score 3):

Assume that $[0,2]/(1,2]$ is homeomorphic to an interval $\langle a, b \rangle$, where $\langle$ stands for $[$ or $($, similarly $\rangle$ for $]$ or $)$.

Then you get a quotient map $p : [0,2] \to \langle a, b \rangle$. Now $p((1,2])$ is a single-point subspace of $\langle a, b \rangle$, say $p((1,2]) = \{ x \}$. Then $(1,2] = p^{-1}(\{x \})$ which must be closed in $[0,2]$ by continity of $p$. This is a contradiction.